# trouble for reinstallation of 'sme' package

Tags: r, github, installation

I would like to load "sme" package in my R. the following error pops up:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sme’:
> package ‘sme’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it

I am trying to re install "sme" package on my R however I am getting the following error:

```
configure: error: Cannot find Gnu Scientific Library >=1.6
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘MotIV’

removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/MotIV’
restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/MotIV’
The downloaded source packages are in
‘/private/var/folders/7g/3knkn0gn5mv1qx1ldgjh4pw00000gn/T/Rtmpkr2Jh2/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: package ‘sme’ is not available (for R version 4.0.2)
2: In install.packages(update[instlib == l, "Package"], l, repos = repos, :
installation of package ‘MotIV’ had non-zero exit status
```

Here is my session Info:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.5

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.2 pillar_1.4.6 BiocManager_1.30.10 prettyunits_1.1.1
[5] remotes_2.2.0 tools_4.0.2 testthat_3.0.0 digest_0.6.27
[9] pkgbuild_1.1.0 pkgload_1.1.0 memoise_1.1.0 lifecycle_0.2.0
[13] tibble_3.0.4 pkgconfig_2.0.3 rlang_0.4.8 cli_2.1.0
[17] rstudioapi_0.11 curl_4.3 withr_2.3.0 dplyr_1.0.2
[21] desc_1.2.0 generics_0.1.0 fs_1.5.0 vctrs_0.3.4
[25] devtools_2.3.2 rprojroot_1.3-2 tidyselect_1.1.0 glue_1.4.2
[29] R6_2.5.0 processx_3.4.4 fansi_0.4.1 sessioninfo_1.1.1
[33] callr_3.5.1 purrr_0.3.4 magrittr_1.5 backports_1.1.10
[37] ps_1.4.0 ellipsis_0.3.1 usethis_1.6.3 assertthat_0.2.1
[41] crayon_1.3.4
```

I googled this issue and followed the instruction on this page to solve the issue which I failed.

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like the installation failed because the `MotIV` package failed - what happens when you try to install that package separately first?

Comment: You have two separate issues. The first is that package `MotIV` is not installing because your system is missing a library required for compilation. But the main problem, as the warning message says is that "package ‘sme’ is not available (for R version 4.0.2)". [It has been removed](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sme/index.html) from the CRAN repository.

Comment: I installed the MotIV separately now I am getting this error: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [sme.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘sme’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/sme’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/sme’

Comment: I am trying to install it from GitHub page: https://github.com/mberk/sme